# Aiogram, бан пользователя прошедшего по ссылке

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Не спрашивайте зачем мне это. Как в фв Aiogram реализовать бан пользователя который пришёл по пригласительной ссылке? Тоесть, он присоединяется к чату с помощью КОНКРЕТОЙ ссылки и после этого бот автоматически его банит. Ничего на ум не приходит

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая штука как deeplink.

```py
#Сначала делаем саму ссылку.
from aiogram.utils.deep_linking import get_start_link
# эту строчку (ниже) обязательно помести в какую-то асинхронную функция для начала иначе будет ошибка
link = await get_start_link('foo') # тут аргумент для ссылки.
# получаем ссылку
# result: 'https://t.me/MyBot?start=foo'
```

Теперь у вас есть ссылка, если кто-то по ней перейдет в тг появится новая кнопка СТАРТ и нажав на нёё сработает передача аргументов

```
# а теперь обрабатываем её вот так
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def handler(message: Message):
    args = message.get_args()
    if args == "foo":
        print("БАН!!!!")
```

[О и если что вот документация по глубоким ссылкам.](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/utils/deep_linking.html)